# rrdtool print (not graph) on same lines?

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

Is there a way to PRINT: everything on 1 line?

Using:

```
PRINT:e:LAST:"Current\:%8.2lf" \
PRINT:e:AVERAGE:"Avg\:%8.2lf" \
PRINT:e:MAX:"Max\:%8.2lf \n" \
```

I get output that looks like:

```
Current:   32.56
Avg:   44.41
Max:  131.90 \n
Current:   28.15
Avg:   65.33
Max:  389.69 \n
Current:   11.98
Avg:   16.45
Max:   59.42 \n
....
```

I would like to get it to look like this:

```
Current:   32.56    Avg:   44.41    Max:  131.90 \n
Current:   28.15    Avg:   65.33    Max:  389.69 \n
```

In the end this will allow me to format the txt to import into excel.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this, as the `PRINT` directive does not work this way.

While the `GPRINT` directive allows you to use \l, \r, \c for starting a new line and specifying justification options, the `PRINT` statement defines a single string.  Each of the strings (IE, each `PRINT` directive) constitutes a new item in the output array, which is printed with one item per line.

If you are calling RRDTool from the API, you get the array of `PRINT` outputs as an array pointer.  This is much more helpful programmatically, but requires some post-processing if you want to do formatting as in your case.

```
rrdtool graph $OPTIONS | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```